# How can I see the remote branch in gitweb interface

Tags: git

In gitweb interface, I see it has a 'heads' section. Is that equals to the 'git branch' locally? And how can I see the remote branch head?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that’s equal to `git branch`. If you want to see the state of specific branch heads, you will have to modify the url:

```
*your-site*?p=*your-project*;a=log;h=*full-ref*
```

`*full-ref*` would be something like `refs/remotes/origin/master`